# Bernstein Inequality (wiki correction?!)

Tags: probability, probability-theory, reference-request

I am having trouble with one of the statements made on this wikipedia page, in particular the second Bernstein Inequality on:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernstein_inequalities_(probability_theory)

Which states the following:

Let $X_1,...,X_n$ be independent random variables. Suppose for some positive integer $L$ and for all $k>1$,

$$ \mathbb{E}[ \lvert X_i\rvert^k ] \leq \frac{1}{2} \mathbb{E}[X_i^2]L^{k-2}k!. $$

Then

$$ P\Big(\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i\geq 2t\Big\{\sum_{i=1}^{n} \mathbb{E}[X_i]^2\Big\}^{1/2}\Big)< \exp(-t^2)$$

for $0 < t < \frac{1}{2L} \big\{\sum_{i=1}^{n}\mathbb{E}[X_i^2]\big\}^{1/2}$.

Firstly, is this statement correct? In the sense that $X_i$'s do not need to be centered at zero?

Secondly, if it is correct, is there an official citation that I could use?

Comment: Relevant: last comment on the [Talk page of the article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk:Bernstein_inequalities_(probability_theory)): (retrieved 04/25/16)
*"The second inequality is incorrect as stated. (For example, if one chooses all X_i to be constant at 5, I think the stated inequality is false for very small t). It's possible that the inequality is true when the X_i have 0 expected value. I tried searching the references for these inequalities but couldn't find the statement of the second one :-( — Preceding unsigned comment added by 198.102.153.2 (talk) 20:20, 10 July 2015 (UTC)"*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to wrong without further assumptions, indeed:

Fix any $L > 0$, and let $X_1,\dots, X_n$ be (almost surely) constant r.v.'s taking value $L$ with probability $1$. Then, for this very value of $L$, and any integer $k > 1$,

$$
\mathbb{E}[\lvert X_i\rvert^k] = L^k \leq \frac{k!}{2}L^k= \frac{1}{2} \mathbb{E}[ X_i^2] L^{k-2} k!.
$$

Yet, we have $\sum_{i=1}^n X_i = nL$ a.s. and $\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n \mathbb{E}[X_i^2]} = \sqrt{n} L$, so
$$
\Pr\left[ \sum_{i=1}^n X_i \geq 2t \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n \mathbb{E}[X_i^2]} \right]=
\Pr\left[ \sqrt{n} \geq 2t \right] = \begin{cases} 1&\text{ if } t\leq \frac{\sqrt{n}}{2} \\ 0 & \text{ o.w.}
 \end{cases}
$$
so the claimed inequality definitely does not hold for $0 < t < \frac{1}{2L} \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n \mathbb{E}[X_i^2]}  = \frac{\sqrt{n}}{2}$, since then $e^{-t^2} < 1$.